# Android Live Wallpaper + Sprite Animation

Tags: android, sprite, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I'm a newbie in programming and is very much interested in knowing how to create my own Android Live Wallpaper. I know that a lot of resources are out there but they were pertaining to some advance level of knowledge.

Can anyone provide a "step by step" sprite animation to be implemented in Live Wallpaper? This by the way helped:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140223/Create-a-live-aquarium-wallpaper-in-Android

but still when I try modifying it, adding random movements, different sprite size, the template was not that "friendly". Please I want to know it.

Answer (score 2):

First download this live wallpaper template:

https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliWallpaperTemplate

Then go here to learn how to do the sprite animations in the renderer class:

http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2012/04/26/rajawali-tutorial-20-animated-sprites/

Hope this helps you.